# Issue in query builder - laravel 5.2

Tags: laravel-5, laravel-query-builder

I have a query which give me error

```
$query=   DB::table('crm_listings as l')
        ->leftJoin('crm_location as loc', 'l.area_location_id', '=', 'loc.loc_id')
        ->select('l.id','l.name','l.price', 'loc.lat', 'loc.lon')
  ->get();

  foreach($query as $i=>$p) { 

    $images_query =DB::table('crm_listings_images')->where('listing_id', $p['id'])->select('image')->get();
     $query[$i]['images'] = $images_query;

  }
  return $query;
```

The error is `Cannot use object of type stdClass as array`

I have these questions

1. Is this a nice way to do it? or we can improve it?
2. how to fix this error?

Comment: One which line you have this error? As its clearly saying you are trying objec to be used as array. Secondly, you can use [Relationships](https://laravel.com/docs/5.0/eloquent#relationships) to make it clean.

Answer (score 2):

you must convert eloquent result to array

```
->get()->toarray();
```

Comment: DB::table('crm_listings as l')
        ->leftJoin('crm_location as loc', 'l.area_location_id', '=', 'loc.loc_id')
        ->select('l.id','l.name','l.price', 'loc.lat', 'loc.lon')
  ->get()->toarray()

Answer (score 0):

- Have look at Eloquent [Relationships](https://laravel.com/docs/5.0/eloquent#relationships)
- Use `$p->id` instead of `$p['id']`.